# Is there a way to replace the Send to messenger button with a custom link?

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/plugin-reference/send-to-messenger

I'd like to replace the button with my custom link so it is consistent with my website design.

```
<div class="fb-send-to-messenger" 
  messenger_app_id="APP_ID" 
  page_id="PAGE_ID" 
  data-ref="PASS_THROUGH_PARAM" 
  color="blue" 
  size="standard">
</div>
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Are you able to place another class in the div and style it ?

Comment: That is not possible. And that users are able to easily recognize the button across different websites is more important than individual design.